# Send File via Http Post

Tags: android, asp.net, http-post

I'm trying to send a file from an Android app to Asp.net server. I tried various examples. But everytime I failed. From serverside:

```
HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = Request.Files;
uploadFiles.Count;
```

Always returns 0.  I have necessary permissions for Android app. There isn't any error. Here is Android app codes:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String url = "http://www.xxxxxx.net/xxxxxx.aspx";


                    File fil = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample.txt");
                    if (fil.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("exists");
                    }
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                            new FileInputStream(fil), -1);
                    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if
                                                // needed
                    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    System.out.println("end");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("asd: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

And serverside:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), true))
        {

            _testData.WriteLine("start");
            HttpFileCollection uploadFiles = Request.Files;
            _testData.WriteLine("file count: " + uploadFiles.Count);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use a library and it did the trick. I still don't know what was wrong with the old code. Nevertheless I used [this library](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and it worked. Here is the app codes in case anyone need it:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.net/this.aspx");

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

final File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/sample.txt");
FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);

builder.addPart("file", fb);
final HttpEntity yourEntity = builder.build();
post.setEntity(yourEntity);
httpClient.execute(post);
```

I didn't change serverside.